# Compare array and remove unmatched values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.locations = [
    { name : "One"},
    { name : "Two"},
    { name : "Three"},
    { name : "India"},
    { name : "Japan"},
    { name : "China"}
];

$scope.tempLocations = [
    { name : "One"},
    { name : "Two"},
    { name : "global"},
];
```

I have two arrays. If `location` doesn't contain some of the names in `tempLocations` I want to remove them from `tempLocation`. In this case i want to remove location  **Global**

I tried the following, but does not work.

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.tempLocations.length;i++){
    var index = $scope.tempLocations.indexOf($scope.locations[i]);
    if(index == -1){
        console.log($scope.tempLocations[i]);
        $scope.tempLocations.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Object comparisons are _ByRef_ so `{} === {}; // false` so you can't do `indexOf`; you will need to loop manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this

```js
$scope = {}

$scope.locations = [
    { name : "One"},
    { name : "Two"},
    { name : "Three"},
    { name : "India"},
    { name : "Japan"},
    { name : "China"}
];

$scope.tempLocations = [
    { name : "One"},
    { name : "Two"},
    { name : "global"},
];
$scope.tempLocations = $scope.tempLocations.filter(function(x) {
     return $scope.locations.some(function(y) {
          return x.name == y.name
     })
})

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify($scope.tempLocations, 0,' ');
console.log($scope);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

If you have many (100+) locations, consider converting them to an "associative array" first, like:

```
validLocations = { "One": 1, "Two": 1 ... etc
```

Comment: @xec You wouldn't want to use `x.name in validLocations` since that would also check anything added to the prototype.  For instance, `Object.prototype.global = ...` would cause the "global" in `tempLocations` to match despite not being in `Locations`.  You want to use `hasOwnProperty()` since that will only check the data structure itself, also netting a small performance increase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through manually as the comment from Paul S. suggests:

```js
var locations = [
  { name : "One"},
  { name : "Two"},
  { name : "Three"},
  { name : "India"},
  { name : "Japan"},
  { name : "China"} ];

var tempLocations = [
  { name : "One"},
  { name : "Two"},
  { name : "global"},
];

var newTempLocations = tempLocations.filter(function(temp){
  return locations.some(function(location){ // stop and return true at first match
    return location.name === temp.name;
  });
})

// print output
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newTempLocations, null, "  ");
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.locations` isn't going to change often, you could do the following:

Build a lookup table for locations

```
var location_lookup = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++ ) {
    location_lookup[$scope.locations[i].name] = true;
}
```

Filter based on the existence of a key

```
$scope.filteredLocations = $scope.tempLocations.filter(function(temp) {
    return location_lookup.hasOwnProperty(temp.name);
});
```

This will prove to be much faster if you're filtering more often than you need to recompute the lookup.  So if `$scope.locations` is static, this would be a good route.

I would advise **against** using `temp.name in location_lookup` as another poster said to since that will also check ALL of the prototyped properties of the `location_lookup` object.  For instance, if another script in your app did `Object.prototype.global = function(){}` then the filter would return "global" as being part of `$scope.locations`, which is not the behavior you want.  `hasOwnProperty` will only check the object itself and not any prototypical inheritance while also being a more efficient method.

Fiddle Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/cu33ojfy/ (also included an implementation that uses Array.prototype to add a `.filter_locations()` method, but adding to Array.prototype is generally a bad idea)